# Killing a while loop that's running in the background without a PID

Tags: linux, bash, loops, pid, kill

I'm a beginner in everything that is part of Linux so please take me slow.

I've created a "script" that's running in the background:

```
while true; do echo "I'm alive" >> alive.log ; done &
```

The output of the script is saved in a file alive.log that's present in the user's home directory. 
The problem is I have no ideea how to kill the loop since it's filling my disk space, if I wish to delete the file then loop will create a new file and fill it with the text "I'm alive" as I've asked it to do.

I tried using:

```
ps - aux | grep while
```

or

```
ps - aux | grep alive
```

The output for the two lines will give me the PID I need but the problem is that the script is a loop which means the PID will change every time it runs itself (recursive) so I can't use the PID to kill the process.

I also tried using:

```
pkill while
killall while
```

The result for both lines is 0 (output can be seen when using pkill while -c "0" or killall while : "while: no process found";

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Type `fg` to get it in the foreground and kill it with ctrl-c.

Comment: ... or `kill %1`. check `help kill`

Comment: Type `jobs`, find your script (e.g. `[1]+ Running ...`), then kill it with `kill %1` (or whatever number was in `[ ]`).

Comment: or `killall script name`, not `killall while`

Comment: If I type jobs I will have 0 output, no lines will be shown so I can't take any info from there. But still the script is still running since I'm constantly checking the file alive.log to see it's size and when to delete it so I can still have space.

Comment: Well, the final solution would be to reboot your system. If you can't do that, `man killall` and see `-u`switch.

Comment: How is this script being executed? Do you start it by hand or is it executed at boot time via some startup script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote the sentence in a script file which named while.sh, and ran it by shell:

```
[edemon@CentOS workspace]$ ./while.sh 
[edemon@CentOS workspace]$
```

There is not PID.
I used top command tool to search my while.sh, it told me:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                 
 4036 edemon    20   0  5268  756  436 R 97.3  0.0   0:07.93 bash                                                                    
 2469 root      20   0 94412  29m  10m S  7.8  2.0   1:49.19 Xorg                                                                    
 2788 edemon    20   0 74300  12m  10m S  1.9  0.9   1:38.79 nm-applet                                                               
 4040 edemon    20   0  2708 1072  796 R  1.9  0.1   0:00.01 top
```

The while's father process is bash, so I killed 4036. The size of alive.log didn't grow any more.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer by @James Brown in the comments.

Type `fg` to get it in the foreground and kill it with `ctrl-c` the fastest way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try out your "script" in the background. When I run

```
while true; do echo "I'm alive" >> alive.log ; done &
```

It returns a process ID to standard output, thereby showing that the process is running in the background. You can kill this process ID with:

```
kill <pid>
```

Comment: Thank you! If you would please upvote my post, that would be appreciated. I also would like to thank Ulysse BN for making the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran that script it's going to show as `bash` if you command `ps -ef`:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
james    27262  2448 98 17:35 pts/3    00:00:12 bash
james     2448  2446  0 Jul19 pts/3    00:04:49 bash
```

(if you are using `bash`) and its parent pid points to a `bash` process as well (PID 27262 is your tight little loop above). So, find all `bash` processes which have a `bash` process as a parent. This could work:

```
$ awk '/^james/ && $NF=="bash" && NR==FNR{a[$2];next} /^james/ && $NF=="bash" && $3 in a{print $2}' <(ps -ef) <(ps -ef)
27262
27359
```

So, those are good candidates for killing. In this case the other is the `ps -ef` and the other is the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Tried rebooting two times, first time didn't work but after the second the loop wasn't present anymore and file wouldn't be rewritten.

Also, after I got rid of it I reentered the script:

```
while true; do echo "I'm alive" >> alive.log ; done &
```

As stated by @ssharma when entering the script the output is a PID, even if the loop keeps changing the PID i was able to kill the loop with that PID.

Thanks for the help!